# class importing in jython

Tags: java, jython

I've got a jython script that needs to include a class (from JUnit in this case). I've got the junit jar in "some/path/junit.jar". My script is:

```
from junit.textui import TestRunner

TestRunner.Main(["name of some class here"])
```

I'm running it like this:

```
java -cp "some/path/junit.jar" -jar jython.jar script.py
```

but it complains that:

```
    from junit.textui import TestRunner
ImportError: No module named junit
```

How can I make it see/import the correct class?

Comment: Jython links for those who never heard of this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jython and http://www.jython.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use -jar option, java ignores classpath. Just run jython class directly like this,

```
java -cp "some/path/junit.jar:some/other/path/jython.jar" org.python.util.jython script.py
```

You have to love their naming convention (all lower-case class name). I assumed the class name would be Jython and it took me a few tries to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

As a - maybe simpler - alternative to ZZ Coder's answer, you can also use the -J-cp parameter on Jython's start script:

```
    jython -J-cp "some/path/junit.jar" script.py
```

(I would have appended this as a comment to the former answer, but my reputation does not allow it yet.)